# Selecting variables with different values in one column

Tags: python, select, drop

I have a dataframe which looks simmilar to this one:

```
Shop   Person  Region 
Shop1  A       North  
Shop2  B       South
Shop3  C       East
Shop4  A       West
Shop5  A       West
```

What I want from my code is to check if there is a person, whose shops are in two regions (So for person A they are in Region North and West).
When code checks that they are in two regions, then it should choose region, where more shops are located and keep those shops and delete the remaining ones from the same person. And to delete shops from one region if the number of shops in both regions is the same (but maybe I will figure it out on my own :) )
So in this case:

```
Shop   Person  Region   
Shop2  B       South
Shop3  C       East
Shop4  A       West
Shop5  A       West
```

It should delete shop1, because it was the only one in North region of this person.
I want to keep shops of the people, who have shops only in one region (so person B and C).

I would be very gratefull for any suggestions, I've been programming for only several months, and I can not think about clever solution for this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['Person', 'Region']).count().sort_values(by='Shop').groupby(level=0).tail(1).reset_index().drop(columns='Shop'))
```

Output

```
    Shop    Person  Region
0   Shop2   B       South
1   Shop3   C       East
2   Shop4   A       West
3   Shop5   A       West
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you!
 I've checked if this code works good for me, but I see that it deletes all of the Shops from North region. 
So if another person has a shop in Northen region it will be deleted. I only want this North region to be deleted from the person, who has shops in two different regions, and has less shops in northern region. 
Any tips?